# Docker file ENTRYPOINT can't detect my start script

Tags: linux, docker, unix, scripting

I'm trying to create a docker image. This image should run a shell script "startService.sh" when the container is created.  The image was built successfully, but when trying to run the image, I get the following error:

```
"./startService.sh: 6: ./startService.sh: source: not found"
```

But I know I copied the startService.sh script into the image. My Dockerfile is shown below.

```
FROM openjdk:8

VOLUME /opt/att/ajsc/config
COPY startService.sh /startService.sh
RUN chmod 777 /startService.sh
ENTRYPOINT ./startService.sh
```

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error isn't saying that your start script isn't found; it's saying that the `source` command (which your script apparently uses) isn't found.  `source` is a bash-specific synonym for the `.` command; if you want your script to be compatible with the Docker image's `/bin/sh`, you need to use `.` instead.